# Problem : Computer shutdown automatically without asking after ~15 minutes on

Tags: shutdown, overheating, temperature

The computer is fresh new installation of Ubuntu 16.04 and the computer decides to halt after ~15 minutes without asking. The fan seems always work 100% and the computer is hot, when not much CPU usage in monitoring.

Here's a a part of `grep -i -e temp -e therm /var/log/syslog*` :

```
critical temperature reaching 91 celcius, shutting down
```

What can I do to fix that kind of problem ? Thanks

Comment: What is the make and model of your computer?

Comment: I had a problem with AMD Turion a while ago - the computer was randomly restarting. The problem was overheating and the computer needed cleaning. Modern processors are equipped with hardware that is preventing overheating. Usually restart is one of symptoms. In your case it is complete shut down. Also please check the power supply - it might be that the power is not big enough to equip the computer with power.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `grep -i -e temp -e therm /var/log/syslog*`. If you dual-boot with Windows, does this same shutdown problem occur in Windows? Is this a laptop, or desktop? How old? Start new comments to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Please see the edit. It indeed looks like a thermal issue and overheating causing the shutdown.

Comment: I'd recommend opening up the case and carefully removing all the dust. Ideally you do this by taking the computer outside and blowing at all the parts with compressed air. It's normally not recommended to use a vacuum cleaner because it might build up static electricity that damages the parts. Also make sure to block the fans from spinning with a finger or a stick while bowing at them to prevent them from working as a generator. If that cleaning does not help, maybe the thermal paste between the CPU and its heat sink needs to get replaced, but that should be done by someone with experience.

Comment: It is a bit complicated, but check the CPU governor setting.  You want it set to a value other than performance to allow the CPU to reduce it's clock speed when not busy.   You should be able to add a file to /etc/sysctl,d to set an appropriate CPU governor.  On some kernels the governor is set per CPU (thread) so you will need multiple settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

After reviewing the syslog with:

```
grep -i -e temp -e therm /var/log/syslog*
```

**It's confirmed that your computer is severely overheating.** The goal would be in the 50-60 Celsius.

I never received an answer if this was a laptop, or desktop, and its age, so I'll have to make some assumptions. Each of the following steps should be performed in < 10 minute steps, followed by a controlled system shutdown so as to keep the machine from burning up.

- open the machine and clean out any dust, especially from the fan and CPU areas
- install `thermald`

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install thermald
```

- if you've got Intel processors, check for, or install `intel-microcode`

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install intel-microcode
```

- enter the BIOS and note its version number (or `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`), and then using the make/model #, check the manufacturers web site for a BIOS update. Apply it if it's newer.
- If you have the technical experience, clean and re-apply thermal paste between the CPU and its heat pipe or fan assembly. This requires previous experience, so if you don't have this experience, please get technical assistance.